# Gap is created between navigation and submenu when viewport is reduced to the point where nav item splits into two lines

Tags: html, css

The nav bar and submenu are perfectly aligned when the view port is full width of the screen. However, when I get to 720px where the nav item "Chinese Calendars" becomes two lines, it creates a gap between the nav bar and the submenu drop down.
I've tried shifting code around and removing things, but can't figure it out. I tried float: right;, creates an overlap instead of falling right below.

```css
* {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

nav {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.nav {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.item {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}

.submenu {
  display: none;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 29px;
  align-items: center;
  align-text: center;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: small;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #2F4F4F;
  color: white;
  justify-content: left;
}

.submenu li {
  margin-left: 6%;
  width: 19%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.submenuActive {
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: left;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1 1 calc(25% - 80px);
  color: black;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
}


/*.item.has-children:hover .submenu {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: left;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex: 1 1 calc(25% - 80px);
    color: black;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
}*/

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.logo {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.logo img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<a class="logo" href="index.html">
  <img src="../../Images/Navigation/Intak Logo 40px High.png" alt="Home" />
</a>

<nav>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="item">
      <a href="../index.html">
        <img src="../../Images/Navigation/Intak Nav Mark -01.png" alt="Home" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item has-children"><a href="../Printing.html">Printing</a>
      <!--  <ul class="submenu">
    <li>Labels & Stickers</li>
    <li>Banners</li>
    <li>A-Frame</li>
    <li>Menu Boards</li>
    <li>Takeout Menus</li>
    <li>Business Cards</li>
    <li>Dine-In Menus</li>
    <li>Posters</li>
    <li>Envelopes</li>
    <li>Chinese Wedding Cards</li>
    <li>Flyers</li>
    <li>Letterheads</li>
    <li>Brochures</li>
    <li>Vinyl</li>
    <li>NCR Forms</li>
    <li>Catalogues</li>
   </ul> -->
    </li>
    <li class="item has-children"><a href="../Graphic Design.html">Graphic Design</a>
      <!--  <ul class="submenu">
    <li>Logo Design</li>
    <li>Ads/Flyers/Promotions</li>
    <li style="text-align: center;">Menu Boards<br>
     (Digital & Boards)</li>
    <li style="text-align: center;">Restaurant Menus<br>
     (Takeout & Dine-In)</li>
   </ul>-->
    </li>
    <li class="item has-children" style="color:#4D4D4D;">Chinese Calendars
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="Cane Wallscroll Calendars.html">Cane Wallscroll Calendars</a></li>
        <li><a href="Wall Calendars.html">Wall Calendars</a></li>
        <li><a href="Mini Calendars.html">Mini Calendars</a></li>
        <li><a href="Desk Calendars.html">Desk Calendars</a></li>
        <li><a href="Special Desk Calendars.html">Special Desk Calendars</a></li>
        <li><a href="Lucky Money Envelopes.html">Lucky Money Envelopes</a></li>
        <li><a href="More.html">More Calendars</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <!--  <li class="item"><a href="../FAQS.html">FAQS</a></li> -->
    <li class="item"><a href="../Contact Us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I need it so regardless of viewport size, the submenu is always touching the navigation bar

https://jsfiddle.net/nqjv3xs5/1/#&togetherjs=lgy6QvwL4g

Greater than 720px:

[image: Greater than 720px]

Less than 720px:

[image: Less than 720px]

Comment: can you provide working example of it in form of pen or fiddle ?

Comment: In the fiddle it's showing how it shows up below 720px. If you copy the code into a html file it will fix when it's greater than 720px

Comment: I don't see dropdowns in your demo.

Comment: dont see any gap ? can you send screenshot of it

Comment: the chinese calendar is a drop down. I'm having a bit of difficulty making it look like one. I don't know why the box doesn't show a finger icon, but rather a text one. I shall attach pictures now

Comment: You have a margin-top of 29px on .submenu.  Is that not what's creating the gap?

Comment: That's to keep it to the bottom of the nav bar, or else it hangs in the middle

Comment: Ok, whatever version of your fiddle I'm looking at needs 10px there.  I'm probably seeing something different. [https://jsfiddle.net/wz8xepm9/](https://jsfiddle.net/wz8xepm9/)

Comment: The fiddle appears different than when I run the html file. it's weird

Comment: What I would try is putting the submenus below the main menu completely, instead of inside the main menu <li>.  That might give you more control over the positioning of the submenu.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192282/discussion-between-sourkrause-and-yabusa).

Comment: Note: Still unresolved